Probabilities with five $6$-sided dice with allowed re-rolls
The scenario that I'm looking at is to do with probabilities to roll results of $5$ or more on a number of $6$-sided dice. The chance to roll $5$ or $6$ on one die is $\dfrac{1}{3}$ as $2$ out of the $6$ faces meet that condition. The probability of getting a result of $1$ to $4$ on a dice is $\dfrac{4}{6}$ = $\dfrac{2}{3}$. The probabilities of getting $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ successes ($5$ or more) on the five dice are:
(Edit: N. F. Taussig pointed out in comments that this
is wrong, and it should be a binomial distribution)
1x 5+ on 5 dice = 1/3 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 1/3
2x 5+ on 5 dice = 1/3 * 1/3 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 1/9
3x 5+ on 5 dice = 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * 1 * 1 = 1/27
4x 5+ on 5 dice = 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * 1 = 1/81
5x 5+ on 5 dice = 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3 = 1/243

So, my main question (assuming that I got the above right, and I might not have?) is that after rolling the $5$ dice, if a player is then allowed to re-roll some or all of the missed dice, how would this affect the overall probability of getting a number of success results?
Example $1$. A player gets $2$ successes ($2$x rolls of $5$+), and is allowed to re-roll $2$ of the missed dice, how do we calculate the overall chance (based on initial roll plus re-roll) of getting $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ successes?
Example $2$. If the re-rolls have a worse chance of success (say that he scores 3 successes and is allowed $2$ re-rolls, but they only are a success on a roll of $6$), how would that affect the overall probabilities?
Example $3$. If the re-rolls have a better chance of success (say that he scored $4$ successes on the initial roll and has 1 re-rolls that is a success on a roll of $4$ or more), how would that affect things
The question then is "What is the chance to get $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ successes with these $5$ dice, when some amount of re-rolls are allowed?"

Are you calculating the probability of obtaining exactly $n$ successes or at least $n$ successes?

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Exactly n successes, i.e., I'd like to know (for the given setup; 5 dice, with x rerolls, and possibly a different success condition on the reroll), what is the probability of exactly 1 success, or exactly 2 successes, or exactly 3 successes, or exactly 4 successes, or exactly 5 successes?

Your probabilities for exactly $k$ successes when a die is rolled five times (without re-rolls) are incorrect.The probability of exactly $k$ successes when a die is rolled $n$ times (without re-rolls) and each roll has probability $p$ of being successful is given by the binomial distribution $\Pr(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n - k}$.

Thanks for pointing this out. If my initial assumptions are incorrect, I would certainly make wrong conclusions.

Consider the following digraph where label of node means how many successes we've achieved (start is $0$, I forgot to put that):

It encodes the ways of reaching the target number of successes. Each arrow from number $a$ to $b$ has probability
$$
\beta_{a,b} := \binom{5-a}{b-a}p^{b-a}(1-p)^{5-b}
$$
This is because we reroll $5-a$ dice and want $b-a$ successes (so that current number of successes becomes $b$). And the probability of success is $p$, you can change that for different layers.
You calculate by layers. Mark the starting node to have probability $1$. Then calculate value for each node in the first layer. For example the node $3$ gets the value (denote the values by $p_j$)
$$
p_3 = \beta_{0,3} = \binom{5}{3}\left({\frac{1}{3}}\right)^3\left({\frac{2}{3}}\right)^2
$$
Then the second layer. For example the node $3$ gets the value
$$
\beta_{0,3}p_0 + \beta_{1,3}p_1 + \beta_{2,3}p_2 + \beta_{3,3}p_3
$$
You can allow rerolling more times by adding more layers and calculating the values for the new layer similarly (always using the $p$-values calculated in the previous layer).

Assume that you have $~m~$ 6 sided-dice, and that $~n~$ re-rolls are allowed.
This question has been asked before at MathSE, and others have commented that the simplest approach is to assume that you will automatically re-roll all $~m~$ dice, $~n~$ times each, and that you will regard a specific die as successful if and only if that specific die showed either $~5~$ or $~6~$ on any of the $~n~$ rolls of that specific die.
So, the probability of a specific die being regarded as successful
is
$$p = 1 - \left[ ~\frac{2}{3} ~\right]^n.$$
Then, the probability of exactly $~k~$ of the $~m~$ dice being regarded as successful is
$$\binom{m}{k} k^p ~(m-k)^{1-p}.$$
